# SQL Query is taking long time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, sql-tuning

The query below is taking long time  and I am trying to tune the query but it seems to be not working .Is there anyway I can rewrite the query. Please help me in tune the query.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TC.V_ID,A.ID,A.NAME 
    FROM OM_A_DATA TC 
       INNER JOIN ACC_DOM_EXT AE ON TC.DOMAINS = AE.DOMAIN
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT A ON A.ID=AE.ACCOUNTID
    WHERE V_ID not in (select distinct V_ID from DATA_ACC_MAP)


OM_A_DATA  has 41,696,776 rows
ACC_DOM_EXT has 106,725 rows
ACCOUNT has 106731 rows
DATA_ACC_MAP has 91021 rows
```

Comment: No need for select DISTINCT in sub-query.

Comment: Are the V_ID columns defined NOT NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often `not exists` works better than `not in`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TC.V_ID, A.ID, A.NAME 
FROM OM_A_DATA TC INNER JOIN
     ACC_DOM_EXT AE
     ON TC.DOMAINS = AE.DOMAIN LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ACCOUNT A
     ON A.ID = AE.ACCOUNTID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DATA_ACC_MAP dam WHERE dam.V_ID = tc.V_ID );
```

Clearly, you should have an index on `DATA_ACC_MAP(V_ID)`.  You should have indexes on other columns as well:  `OM_A_DATA(V_ID, DOMAINS)`, `ACC_DOM_EXT(DOMAIN, ACCOUNTID)`, and `ACCOUNT(ID, NAME)`.

Answer (score 1):

Either Remove the `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TC.V_ID, A.ID, A.NAME 
FROM OM_A_DATA TC 
INNER JOIN ACC_DOM_EXT AE ON TC.DOMAINS = AE.DOMAIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT A ON A.ID = AE.ACCOUNTID
WHERE V_ID NOT IN (SELECT V_ID FROM DATA_ACC_MAP)
```

Or Use a `INNER JOIN` rather than sub query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TC.V_ID, A.ID, A.NAME 
FROM OM_A_DATA TC 
INNER JOIN ACC_DOM_EXT AE ON TC.DOMAINS = AE.DOMAIN
INNER JOIN DATA_ACC_MAP AD ON TC.V_ID != AD.V_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT A ON A.ID = AE.ACCOUNTID
```

Or Use a `LEFT JOIN` rather than sub query and an altered `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TC.V_ID, A.ID, A.NAME 
FROM OM_A_DATA TC 
INNER JOIN ACC_DOM_EXT AE ON TC.DOMAINS = AE.DOMAIN
LEFT JOIN DATA_ACC_MAP AD ON TC.V_ID = AD.V_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT A ON A.ID = AE.ACCOUNTID
WHERE AD.V_ID IS NULL
```